# Xcode 7 warning: The launch image does not have a valid extension

Tags: ios, xcode7, launchimage

Xcode 7 has warnings for my launch image set. It reads:

> The launch image set "LaunchImage" references a file "Default@2x.PNG", but that file does not have a valid extension.

I tried removing the image and put it back again with no luck. What is it warning about and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try changing `Default@2x.png` instead of `Default@2x.PNG`.

Comment: It wasn't used to be a problem in previous Xcode versions! But Xcode 7 seems to care about names. Thanks!

Comment: I have small letter .jpg and still have the warning!

Comment: it has worked, I was experiencing same error

Answer (score 4):

Can't comment, yet found this helpful:

After renaming the image's extension name to lowercase the warning goes away
(as explained in the accepted answer: `.PNG` `->` `.png`)

If the warning doesn't go away, clean the project by going to 
`Product` `->` `Clean`

(or just: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>)

Answer (score 2):

If you have the file `Image.PNG`, convert it into `Image.png`, and if you have the file extension `Image.JPG`, convert it into `Image.jpg`.

Make sure your images have extension with lowercase letters, not capital letters. Hope this will help!