# Jpeg images in Xcode project reported to to be invalid

Tags: ios, xcode

After upgrading (Swift and Xcode - some time ago already), I now have a warning for every .JPG image in my project (I have 200+ JPG images in the project):

> The image set "Image1" references a file "Image1.JPG", but that file
>   does not have a valid extension.

How do I get rid of the warnings/fix the root cause of the issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32632577/xcode-7-warning-the-launch-image-does-not-have-a-valid-extension

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like `.JPG` is not a valid file extension for Xcode 7. Try changing all `.JPG` to `.jpg` and the problem should be gone.

Same rule applies to images with `.PNG` extensions too.

Comment: It works. Thanks. Now to go rename 140 images to lower case and import them into the project again :-( Whats worse is that this is the way that the images have been exported from the Photos program - one program does it this way and another does not accept it.

Comment: This same issue caused the issue on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32632577/xcode-7-warning-the-launch-image-does-not-have-a-valid-extension earlier!

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, it's true that you need to use a lowercase .jpg extension, but you don't have to import all of the images again. You can just rename the image files in the imageset folder to have a lowercase extension and edit the contents.json file associated with it to reference the lowercase .jpg extension.

Answer (score 0):

To rename hundreds of image extensions in one go:
In Xcode right click an image > Show in Finder > change to List view (or press ⌘+2) > highlight / select all folders with .imageset > press right arrow to expand all in one go > now select all folders including all image files inside > right click > Rename X items > Replace Text > Find: .JPG Replace With: .jpg.